# cannot enter text in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm able to see the layout of tinymce but i am not able to enter text. Please, help me
solve this issue.

Currently, you can see what I'm trying say [here](http://www.kapoorhandlooms.com/kkn/recent-members-sk-2/0). To check the TinyMCE editor, click in the "Recent Members" text, that's green colored.

i have linked the script file too..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/tinymce-sk/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".flirt-message",
    plugins: "smileys",
    toolbar: "smileys"
});
```

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <form method="post">
           <textarea name="message" autofocus="" class="flirt-message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" >
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please, post some code, so we can help you with this problem. We can't do anything if you don't help us. Currently, I can't see any TinyMCE editor in your website, so, I can't help you at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to apply TinyMCE in the fields like "About Me", "Nationality" and others in this page: http://www.kapoorhandlooms.com/kkn/view-user-profile-from-dashboard-sk/?userID=39 ?

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you're trying do. I need to click on the green button to see the TinyMCE editor.

Comment: Last comment, you need help us. Please, post the code of your page, we really need this to debug and understand what's problem. Other way, I can't and I don't will help you anymore.

Comment: Instead `class`, try to apply an id to your textarea. `<textarea name="message" autofocus="" id="flirt-message">` and in your javascript put: `selector: "#flirt-message"`. Post what happens here, in the comments.

Comment: i think jquery installation files and tiny mce files are conflicting ,because when textarea is outside <div id="dialog"> then it is working fine

Comment: Okay, then try to put this in your javascript: `selector: "#dialog#flirt-message"` and post your results.

Comment: Facing the same problem in my code